# Авторы реакций сообщения discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Мне нужно получить **массив всех пользователей использовавших любую реакцию**. У меня есть нужное сообщение (оно определяется по id). Я пробовал `msg.reactions.users()`, `msg.reactions[x].users()`, `list(msg.reactions[x].users())`, но все безуспешно. Либо ошибка атрибута, либо не получается конвертировать в лист.

```py
@bot.slash_command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def check(inter:disnake.CommandInteraction, msg:disnake.Message):
    #msg - нужное сообщение
    users = ...
```

*В документации тоже ничего не нашёл*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переходим к классу реакции и по ключевому слову `async for` видим, что метод [`users`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Reaction.users) возвращает вам не список пользователей, а итератор, который можно использовать в цикле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаем на него и получаем примеры использования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

И далее, имея все это несложно написать код:

```py
# msg - нужное сообщение

users = []

for reaction in msg.reactions:
    async for user in reaction.users():
        users.append(user)

# вывод имен пользователей для проверки
for user in users:
    print(user.name)
```

Или можно заполнить список проще, через генератор:

```py
users = [user for reaction in msg.reactions async for user in reaction.users()]
```

Comment: Выручил, спасибо